# Why the line of Linear Regression is same as deming regression?

Tags: linear-regression

This is not a coding question. My doubt is purely mathematical. Say I take three points (1,2) (2,1) and (4,3)

A. I calculate the least fit line for linear regression. Simple linear regression(which minimizes the sum of errors in y/drop vertical lines from the points to the line)

B. I calculate the deming regression, which minimizes the actual distance of points from a line (drop perpendiculars from the points to the line)

My question is that the lines obtained in both A and B are same. In this case : y = 1 + 0.429x Why is this happening, isnt this counterintuitive?